# Rails: where to enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, cors

I'm trying to load a link in my coffeescript file like so:

```
$.ajax hobby.link,
  type: 'GET'
  dataType: 'html'
  error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
    console.log "AJAX Error"
  success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    console.log "Successful AJAX call"
```

and have installed

```
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
```

and added

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

to my application.rb, but everytime I get

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

What else do I need to do to make these loads work?

Note that I'm currently performing that ajax call to three different links in a row.

Comment: `cannot load http://www.example.com/` are you sure you're querying `localhost:3000` with ajax?

Comment: @amingilani could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you're asking me.

Comment: The error above says `XMLHttpRequest cannot load  http://www.example.com/`, check your ajax code to see if you've got `example.com` hardcoded in there.

Comment: I just put that link in as an example. The actual links I'm trying to load are other third-party URLs too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rack::Cors` deals with allowing or denying CORS for *your own* website and domain. It cannot affect the CORS configuration for any other domain.

For example, your website might be `http://example.com`, and you're trying to send an AJAX request to `http://example.net`. Since example.net is not under your control, you don't control its CORS settings, and neither does `Rack::Cors`. This means that if example.net has disallowed AJAX requests, you can't do anything about it.

Talk to the administrator of the service you're trying to call, and see if you can persuade them to allow AJAX requests (at least from your domain).

Answer (score 0):

The error code suggests that the 3rd party site you're trying to load doesn't allow requests from outside their own domain. It isn't a problem with your application, they disallow requests that don't originate from their own domain.

This is a measure against [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) attacks. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work/21310171#21310171) answer for an explanation of how CORS works.

Comment: these websites are public domains

Comment: @rigdonmr yes, but they don't allow ajax requests that originate from outside their own domain. Basically, when your browser sends a request to siteA originating form a siteLocalhost, siteA gives your browser a whitelist of domains the request should have originated from, and siteLocalhost is not on it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21310171/3970701

Comment: so what situations does the tutorial in this link work in: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ ?

Comment: Which link? I think we should take this to chat.

Comment: the link in my previous comment

Comment: @rigdonmr please join me here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125550/discussion-for-40008944